# Android: Calculating Rotation and Placement of Sprite On a Line

Tags: android, andengine, trigonometry

I'm trying to place a series of square Sprites on a line drawn by the user on my Android.

I have the x/y coordinates of the finger down/finger up points with:

`Vector2[] points = { new Vector2(mFingerStartX, mFingerStartY), new Vector2(mFingerEndX, mFingerEndY) };`

and have the distance with:

`float distance = points[0].dst(points[1]);`

and the number of blocks needed (64x64px) for the line:

`int blockNumber = (int) Math.floor(distance / 64);`

But I don't know where to go from here! My end goal is to get the square sprites lines up and each rotated in the direction of the line, so that they form a smooth line together.

The way I'm imagining it would go is for each block needed, place the block at a point on the line, rotate it to the correct orientation, move 64px down the line, and repeat until the required number of blocks are placed.

**Summarized**: How do I get the degree of rotation, and the points where the sprites need to be placed?

**EDIT:** This is how far I've gotten. I have the rotation down well, but I can't seem to get the Sprites to line up in the line correctly. Anyone see where I might be going wrong?

```
            float mFingerEndX = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
            float mFingerEndY = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();

            Vector2[] points = { new Vector2(mFingerStartX, 800 - mFingerStartY), new Vector2(mFingerEndX, 800 - mFingerEndY) };
            float distance = points[0].dst(points[1]);

            int blockNumber = (int) Math.floor(distance / 64);  //get the number of ice blocks needed to fill the area

            double angle = Math.atan2(points[0].x - points[1].x, points[0].y - points[1].y);
            double degrees = Math.toDegrees(angle);

            Debug.d("Degrees: " + String.valueOf(degrees));

            for (int i = 0; i < blockNumber; i++) {
                double deltaX = Math.cos(degrees) * 32;
                double deltaY = Math.sin(degrees) * 32;

                float xLocation = (float) ((i * deltaX) + mFingerStartX);
                float yLocation = (float) ((i * deltaY) + mFingerStartY);
                final Sprite iceSprite = new Sprite(xLocation, yLocation, this.mIceBlockRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                iceSprite.setRotation((float) (180 - Math.abs(degrees)));
                mScene.attachChild(iceSprite);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each `blockNumber`, calculate the relative rotation from one end of that portion of the user-drawn line to the other. This is the hypotenuse of a right triangle, and since you have the vertical and the horizontal distance of that segment as well, you can get the angle away from vertical with some basic trig. Rotate the sprite to that angle, and place it (with the bottom middle aligned with the bottom point). Repeat this for every sprite on the line until you get to the top.

The sprites won't be seamless if the user drawn line isn't very smooth, though, but that's a whole other issue.